# What is the most efficient way to query all documents from a specific partition in Partitioned Collection in Azure Document DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I created a Partitioned Collection in Document db and I want to be able to query all documents in a specific partition from this collection without doing a cross partition query. For the sake of example, lets say I am writing Car objects to this Collection and the Partition Key field is Car.Manufacturer. Manufacturer is a string.

I want to query all Car documents that belongs to a specific Manufacturer from my partitioned collection.

What would be the most efficient way to do this ? Currently I do below and I know this causes the Cross partition query - even though I am setting the Partition key explicitly in the query (to "Mercedes")

```
IDocumentQuery<Car> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Car>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("dbName", "CollectionName"))
                .Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Mercedes")
                .AsDocumentQuery();

List<Car> mercedesCars = new List<Car>();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (Car car in await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Car>())
                {
                    data.Add(car);
                }
            }
```

I am looking for a solution to make this query without causing a cross partition query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the partition by providing the `FeedOptions` with your query and setting `PartitionKey` property.

Your query will look like this:

```
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Mercedes") };
IDocumentQuery<Car> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Car>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("dbName", "CollectionName"), feedOptions)
            .Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Mercedes")
            .AsDocumentQuery();

List<Car> mercedesCars = new List<Car>();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (Car car in await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Car>())
    {
        data.Add(car);
    }
}
```